# How to work with OUT-value in ConcurrentDictionary.TryGetValue?

Tags: c#, concurrentdictionary

Help me pls to understand how does ConcurrentDictionary work?
I have this:

```
UsersOnlineClass client;
if (UsersOnlineDictionary.TryGetValue(comClientID, out client)) { }
```

I have to change some value in *client* and save changes in ConcurrentDictionary. As will be right?

```
UsersOnlineClass updatedClient = new UsersOnlineClass();
updatedClient = client; //make copy
updatedClient.someInt = -1;
if (UsersOnlineDictionary.TryUpdate(client.Client_id, updatedClient, client)) { }
```

or I can just do so, and that will be enough?

```
client.someInt = -1;
```

Comment: Just test and you will see. Since `UsersOnlineClass` seems to be reference type, you can use both ways, although one liner is easier to understand

Comment: Is `UsersOnlineClass` a `class` or a `struct`?  If a class, `updatedClient = client; //make copy` will not actually copy the class.  If a struct, you don't need to copy it locally, because it will already have been copied out of the dictionary.  ([See here on `struct assignment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saxz13w4.aspx)).

Answer (score 2):

If *UsersOnlineClass* is a *class*, your code is fine (as long as "someInt" is thread-safe), since *client* then is a reference to the object in the dictionary. If *UsersOnlineClass* is a *struct*, however, you must do as in your example code, since *client* will then be a copy for what's in the dictionary.